# Read a CSV in Logstash level and filter on basis of the extracted data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, elk

I am using Metricbeat to get process-level data and push it to Elastic Search using Logstash.

Now, the aim is to categorize the processes into 2 tags i.e the process running is either a browser or it is something else.

I am able to do that statically using this block of code :

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter{
    if [process][name]=="firefox.exe" or [process][name]=="chrome.exe" {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "process.type" => "browsers" }
            convert => {
            "process.type" => "string"
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "process.type" => "other" }
        } 
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    # manage_template => false
    index => "metricbeatlogstash"
  }
}
```

But when I try to make that if condition dynamic by reading the process list from a CSV, I am not getting any valid results in Kibana, nor a error on my LogStash level.

The CSV config file code is as follows :

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
  file{
        path=>"filePath"
        start_position=>"beginning"
        sincedb_path=>"NULL"
    }
}
filter{
    csv{
        separator=>","
        columns=>["processList","IT"]
    }
    if [process][name] in [processList] {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "process.type" => "browsers" }
            convert => {
            "process.type" => "string"
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "process.type" => "other" }
        } 
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    # manage_template => false
    index => "metricbeatlogstash2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do does not work that way in logstash, the events in a logstash pipeline are independent from each other.

The events received by your `beats` input have no knowledge about the events received by your `csv` input, so you can't use fields from different events in a conditional.

To do what you want you can use the `translate` filter with the following config.

```
translate {
    field => "[process][name]"
    destination => "[process][type]"
    dictionary_path => "process.csv"
    fallback => "others"
    refresh_interval => 300
}
```

This filter will check the value of the field `[process][name]` against a dictionary, loaded into memory from the file `process.csv`, the dictionary is a `.csv` file with two columns, the first is the name of the browser process and the second is always `browser`.

```
chrome.exe,browser
firefox.exe,browser
```

If the filter got a match, it will populate the field `[process][type]` (not `process.type`) with the value from the second column, in this case, always `browser`, if there is no match, it will populate the field `[process][type]` with the value of the `fallback` config, in this case, `others`, it will also reload the content of the `process.csv` file every 300 seconds (5 minutes)

Comment: Great stuff! Plus it also provides one with the flexibility to add in a new entry to the CSV (say edge.exe?) and have it picked up in the next 5 minutes at the latest.